# How to debug Cognito's idpresponse endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, paypal, openid, amazon-cognito

I'm setting up OIDC provider for Cognito User pool. The open id connect service I'm using is Paypal. At the step where paypal issues code and redirects to cognito's `/oauth2/idpresponse` endpoint after which cognito is supposed to exchange the code for access token, I'm receiving `"Exception processing authorization code"` error. As you can see the error message is not very discriptive.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I did setup open id connect properly. Setup client settings in cognito and etc.

These are the endpoints I'm using for openid connect:
`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/signin/authorize`
`https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice`
`https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token/userinfo`
`https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/certs`

In app client settings I have auth code grant flow and implicit flow enabled. I have custom domain setup. I provided paypal client id and secret

My guess is if I'm able to somehow debug idpresponse endpoint I should be able to solve the problem. Is there any way to do that? Maybe cloudwatch?

Comment: Similar thread (with no answer) here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=905043&#905043

Comment: Same here using a pre signup trigger with Google or Facebook

Comment: Any luck? I'm facing the same issue, using Google, it was working for me, but not anymore.

Comment: @Mantas YMMV, but I've discovered that as of now, any custom error conditions you return from your PreSignUp trigger will now result in this generic error message being passed back in the callback URL, rather than information you had wanted to return in your custom error.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about debugging Cognito's endpoints, but I had the same problem and fixed it by doing the following:

1. Go to your User Pool in AWS.
2. In the side navigation under **Federation**, select **Attribute mapping**.
3. Click the tab of the identity provider you're having issues with (in my case it was Google).
4. There should be three columns, *Capture*, *Google attribute*, and *User pool attribute*. Make sure all of the attributes that are checked in the *Capture* column are mapped to an attribute in the *User pool attribute* column.

   **UPDATE:**

   After submitting this answer, I realized that the checkboxes in the *Capture* column are not checked by default. **If you marked any attributes as required in the *Attributes* section of your user pool, then you need to map those attributes to the attributes provided by your external identity providers**.

   For example, I marked *email* as a required attribute in my user pool settings. So, when I added Google as an identity provider, I had to go to *Federation->Attribute mapping*, click on the tab for Google, check the box in the *Capture* column next to *email*, and select *Email* from the dropdown box in the *User pool attribute* column.

After taking these steps, the sign in work-flow worked for me.

My guess is the auth flow works just fine between Cognito and your identity provider, but Cognito doesn't know how to map the attributes returned from the identity provider to the attributes you have set in your user pool (in **General settings->Attributes** under the *Which standard attributes are required* section).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but unfortunately didn't work :/

Comment: There may be other reasons why this won't fix the problem, but if you _don't_ have things configured correctly as described in this answer, it _will be_ one of the reasons it's not working.